Pipe read maximum number of elements?
I tried to write a simple reader and writer program.
reader:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 65600 //921600 // 640*480*3
#define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); }

int main()
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    long int i;

    if ( (fd = open("./shared/test", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        err("open")

    while( (n = read(fd, buf, BUFFSIZE) ) > 0) {
        printf("Read (%d): ", n);
        for (i=0; i<BUFFSIZE; i++)
            printf("%c", buf[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    close(fd);
    
    return 0;
}

writer:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFSIZE  65600 //921600 // 640*480*3
#define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); }


int main()
{
    int fd;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    long int i, j;

    mkfifo("./shared/test", 0666);
    if ( (fd = open("./shared/test", O_WRONLY)) < 0)
        err("open")

    // main loop
    j=0;
    while (1){
    for (i=0;i<BUFFSIZE;i++){
        buf[i]= j + '0';
    }
    j++;
    buf[BUFFSIZE-1]=j + '0';
    
    write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    sleep(10);
    }

    close(fd);
    
    return 0;
}

The program correctly works up to BUFFSIZE 65535 (2^16-1).
When I tried with bigger number it gives me for example:
Read (65536): 0000000000000000000000000000000000000 and after junk elements
How can I use it for bigger number of elements?
Thanks,
Joe

In the reader you print from (i=0; i<BUFFSIZE; i++). You should instead do i < n. There is no guarantee the OS will feed you the entire amount the writer wrote in a single batch.

You don't check the result of write(). It is possible that less bytes were accepted/sent.

It is possible to guarantee the  writer wrote in a single batch all?

See the PIPE_BUF section of man 7 pipe

Modern POSIX systems usually limit the information in a pipe to  64 KiB (65536 bytes).  Historically, the capacity of a pipe was often 5 KiB (5120 bytes); POSIX only requires 4 KiB (4096 bytes).  Your reader code should only report on the number of bytes that were read (as diagnosed by @Verpous).  Always pay attention to the number of bytes read, and don't try to manipulate bytes that were not read.  The writer will wait until all the data that you request to be written has been written. However, if there is no reader, or the reader is slow, it will wait until there is space in the pipe again.

If the writer tries to write less than the pipe buffer size bytes, then the write will be atomic (not mixed with other writes).  If the writer tries to write more than that, then the data will be sent in batches.  You have only one writer, so there won't be any inter-weaving of the data.  But, at the physical level, the data will be sent in batches of the pipe buffer size (and an odd size chunk if the data sent isn't an exact multiple of the pipe buffer size).  (See PIPE_BUF and _POSIX_PIPE_BUF in <limits.h>)

Oh — bother!  I see looking at the <limits.h>
page in the POSIX standard that _POSIX_PIPE_BUF is 512, not 4096 as I stated in my first comment.  I checked the 1997 and 2004 standards; it was the same in them.  I misremembered.

OK thanks all! I think that for this task, I will use shared memory instead.

You define #define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); } and use it without a trailing semicolon: err("open").  You could, and I'd argue should, allow a trailing comma err("open"); by using a do-once loop in the macro: #define err(mess) do { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); } while (0).  This requires a semicolon, which makes the code look more like a regular function.  Macros are often all in upper-case to emphasize that they are macros.  Making a function out of the macro could be a good idea, too (possibly a static inline function).

You could look at the Linux err(3) family of functions.  You could also look at my code that is available in my SOQ (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files stderr.c and stderr.h in the src/libsoq sub-directory.  They do more or less the same job — though my code has more capabilities (and the err(3) code does one thing my code does not, namely it determines the program name — argv[0] to main() automatically).

I’m voting to close this question because the OP is satisfied with the commentary and plans to use a different way of communicating between processes.

There's no need for both programs to have the same buffer size, if you do proper checking of your buffer.  That's the idea of the pipe.  Checking the read() and write() calls for incomplete writes or reads is important, and to consider that if a read doesn't read a complete buffer, the rest of it will have no interesting data to be printed.   Check this copy of your code (corrected in places you make mistakes) and see how things go.
Normally, a reading process will be blocked until all its buffer is filled with data, but if no more data is available (because all writer processes have closed their writing side) the process will be unblocked, received all the buffer data, until there's no more data in the buffer stream, and EOF will be signalled then (read() returns 0 characters without blocking on EOF)
Normally, a writing process will be blocked if its buffer is larger than the pipe internal available buffer, and the write() system call will block, waiting for more space to be available, until all its buffer has been written.  This event will release the writer from the write() system call and return to the process.
This system makes the reader and the writer processes never sense the internal buffering in the pipe.  Indeed the data could be copied directly from the writer to the reader, but this would block both processes in a rendez vous, sleeping the reader until a writer starts writing data, and releasing only the process that has finished copying its data to the other side, which is not desirable, so a buffer has been implemented to allow avoiding the rendez-vous for readers and writers.
reader.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 65600 //921600 // 640*480*3
#define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); }

int main()
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    long int i;

    mkfifo("test", 0666);
    if ( (fd = open("test", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        err("open")

    while( (n = read(fd, buf, BUFFSIZE) ) > 0) {
        printf("Read (%zd): ", n);
        /* you cannot warrant that
         * BUFFSIZE chars have been read, so use
         * n, instead of BUFFSIZE */
        for (i = 0; i < n && i < 32; i++)
            printf("%c", buf[i]);
        if (i >= 32) printf(" ...\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        err(strerror(errno));
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

writer.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFSIZE  921600 // 640*480*3
#define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); }

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    long int i, j;

    mkfifo("test", 0666);
    if ( (fd = open("test", O_WRONLY)) < 0)
        err("open")

    /* you only need to do this once, as you never
     * change the buffer contents. */
    char *p = buf;
    for (i = 1; i <= BUFFSIZE; i++, p++) {
        /* this will write the pattern ....,....;....,....;
         * in the buffer. */
        switch(i % 10) {
        case 5:  *p = ','; break;
        case 0:  *p = ';'; break;
        default: *p = '.'; break;
        }
    }
    /* hmmmm.... j + '0'??? sure? I think you need
     * this, instead: */
    // buf[BUFFSIZE-1]='\0';  // '0' is not the same as '\0'

    /* but you don't need it, as you tell write() where to
     * stop writing */

    // main loop
    for (j = 0;; j++) {
        /* as you defined buf of BUFFSIZE chars, sizeof buf will be
         * that number, if you specify sizof(buf) you will write the
         * last \0 char, and you don't want that to occur... or yes? */
        printf("#%ld:\n", j);

        ssize_t n;
        char *p = buf;
        size_t to_go = sizeof buf;
        while ((n = write(fd, p, to_go)) > 0) {
            p     += n; /* advance the pointer n positions */
            to_go -= n; /* reduce the chars to go in n */
        }
        if (n < 0) {
            /* we got out of the loop because n < 0, this is because
             * an error happened to write() */
            err(strerror(errno));
        }
        sleep(10);
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

Introduce also a delay in the reader (with a different time) and you will see how the slowest process slows the fastest, but no data is lost.
